# Error on phpmyadmin config file

Tags: phpmyadmin, xampp

phpMyAdmin - Error

Wrong permissions on configuration file, should not be world writable!
How do I solve the above error which results when I try to access 
localhost/phpmyadmin

Comment: Well, by making the file _not_ world-writeable? Since such thing _always_ is a security issue?

Comment: Looks like that is a unixoid platform you are working on? No idea why people use `xampp` in such a situation instead of the easy and prepared packages provided, but anyway: should be something like `chmod go-w /path/to/that/config/file`...

Answer (score 0):

You just need to chmod 0755 the file, see below

```
chmod 0755 config.inc.php
```